# ArcGIS Javascript API - addLayers

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I working on a project trying to add feature layers from ArcGIS online to a web map application using the JavaScript API where a user can toggle the layers on and off through a HTML tick box. The layers are importing correctly and are displayed when the tick boxes are bypassed but I can get it to work with the tickboxes. I have hacked code from ArcGIS samples etc so it must be some small thing I keep missing!

Here is the code - basically all I want is the layers to toggle on and off on top of a constant base map based on which checkboxes the user ticks on and off

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples
      on iOS devices-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Select with feature layer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/js/dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/js/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #mapDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
      #messages{
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        max-width: 15em;
        padding: 0.5em;
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        top: 20px;
        z-index: 40;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/"></script>
    <script>

        var map;
        require([
        "esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/tasks/query", "esri/geometry/Circle",
        "esri/graphic", "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
        "esri/config", "esri/Color", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!", "dojo/on", "dojo/query", "dojo/domReady!", "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer", "esri/layers/ImageParameters",
      ], function (
        Map, FeatureLayer,
        Query, Circle,
        Graphic, InfoTemplate, SimpleMarkerSymbol,
        SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleRenderer,
        esriConfig, Color, dom, on, query, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, ImageParameters
      ) {
          // use a proxy page if a URL generated by this page is greater than 2000 characters
          //
          // this should not be needed as nearly all query & select functions are performed on the client
          esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy";

          map = new Map("mapDiv", {
              basemap: "streets",
              center: [-120.303130, 36.542750],
              zoom: 5,
              slider: false
          });

          //add the census block points in on demand mode. Note that an info template has been defined so when
          //selected features are clicked a popup window will appear displaying the content defined in the info template.
          var Offices = new FeatureLayer("URL", {
              infoTemplate: new InfoTemplate("Block: ${BLOCK}", "${*}"),
              outFields: ["*"]
          });

          var Northridge = new FeatureLayer("URL", {
              infoTemplate: new InfoTemplate("Block: ${BLOCK}", "${*}"),
              outFields: ["*"]
          });

          var Associates = new FeatureLayer("URL", {
              infoTemplate: new InfoTemplate("Block: ${BLOCK}", "${*}"),
              outFields: ["*"]
          });

          // selection symbol used to draw the selected census block points within the buffer polygon
          var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
          SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE,
          12,
          new SimpleLineSymbol(
            SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_NULL,
            new Color([247, 34, 101, 0.9]),
            1
          ),
          new Color([207, 34, 171, 0.5])
        );
          Offices.setSelectionSymbol(symbol);

          //make unselected features invisible
          var nullSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().setSize(10);
          var RedCircle = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().setSize(8);

          Offices.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(nullSymbol));

          on(dom.byId("layer0CheckBox"), "change", updateLayerVisibility);
          on(dom.byId("layer1CheckBox"), "change", updateLayerVisibility);
          on(dom.byId("layer2CheckBox"), "change", updateLayerVisibility);

          function updateLayerVisibility() {
              var inputs = query(".list_item");
              var inputCount = inputs.length;
              //in this application layer 2 is always on.
              visibleLayerIds = [2];

              for (var i = 0; i < inputCount; i++) {
                  if (inputs[i].checked) {
                      visibleLayerIds.push(inputs[i].value);
                  }
              }

              if (visibleLayerIds.length === 0) {
                  visibleLayerIds.push(-1);
              }

              map.addLayers(visibleLayerIds);
          }
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
<br />
    <br />
        Layer List : <span id="layer_list"><input type='checkbox' class='list_item' id='layer0CheckBox' value="Northridge" />Earthquake  
          <input type='checkbox' class='list_item' id='layer1CheckBox' value="Offices" />Offices
          <input type='checkbox' class='list_item' id='layer2CheckBox' value="Associates" />Associates
        </span><br />
        <br />


    <div id="mapDiv"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Done this long time ago

```
 changeVLayerVisibility: function(names) {
    Ext.Array.each(map.graphicsLayerIds, function(id) {
        map.getLayer(id).setVisibility(names.indexOf(id) !== -1);
    });
},
```

Check an example here: http://smart-tech-group.com/arcgismap/
The map-related logic is stored in http://smart-tech-group.com/arcgismap/APP/view/ArcMapViewer.js I was a js-newbie back then, so feel free to argue on my code style;)

Answer (score 0):

1. In function updateLayerVisibility, the map.addLayers usage is wrong.
   you should add featurelayers, graphic layers, dynamic layers or tiled layers, not the ids, unless you store them in the array visibleLayerIds.
2. You may consider use ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer to control visible layer ids. Then use setVisibleLayers API see https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html
3. FeatureLayer is usually for a single layer, use service like MapServer/2 or FeatureServer/2.